# How do I group aggregated data a certain way

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I have the following sample transactional item receipt data, consisting of Item, Vendor and Receipt Date:

| Item | Vendor | Receipt_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| A | 2 | 2021-01-31 00:00:00.000 |
| B | 1 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
| B | 2 | 2021-02-10 00:00:00.000 |
| B | 3 | 2021-02-20 00:00:00.000 |
| C | 7 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 |

I want to select the Vendor for each Item, based on the last (max) Receipt Date, so the expected result for the above sample would be:

| Item | Last_Vendor_For_Receipt |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 7 |

I can group the data per Item and Vendor, but I cannot figure out how to achieve the above expected result with an outer query. I'm using SQL Server 2012. Here's the initial query:

```
select
    ir.Item
    ,ir.Vendor
    ,max(ir.Receipt_Date) Last_Receipt_Date
from
    ItemReceipt ir
```

I checked online and in the forum, but it was hard to search for my specific question.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's difficult to search for something when you don't know exactly what the "thing" is called ;-) A few phrases that might help are "top N per group" or "greatest-n-per-group"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach using `TOP` with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Receipt_Date DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you select the desired max date per item:

```
select max(Receipt_Date) as max_rcpt_date
,      Item
from   your_unknown_table
group by Item
```

And then you can use this as a subquery to get the vendor:

```
select Item
,      Vendor
from   your_unknown_table   
where  ( Receipt_Date, Item ) in 
             ( select max(Receipt_Date) as max_rcpt_date
               ,      Item
               from   your_unknown_table
               group by Item
             )
```

This will work in Oracle. I'm not sure if this subquery-structure in SQL-Server wil work.

Comment: `where  ( Receipt_Date, Item ) in ...` this is not valid for SQL Server

Comment: Thanks, do you know what the MSSQL equivalent might be? @Squirrel

Comment: `FROM your_unknown_table  as t WHERE Receipt_Date In (SELECT MAX(Receipt_Date) FROM your_unknown_table as x WHERE x.Item = t.Item)`

Comment: Note, one small difference between using max(...) and row_number() is that the former could return multiple vendors per item if they share the exact same Receipt_Date.